# Converting ActiveRecord object to an array

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

```
 collected_cards.each do |card|
      ac = Card.find_by('name like ?', "#{card}")

      if ac.nil?
        next
      else
        confirmed_cards << ac
      end
    end
```

I'm parsing an array of strings. For each string i try to collect a name from my postgres `ac = Card.find_by('name like ?', "#{card}")`

The problem is, the AC object is not being perceived as an array or even a hash by Ruby/Rails, which leads me to this error when I try to render it in my view:

```
undefined method `each' for #<Card:0x007f9368494a50>
```

Here's a small snippet of the view code:

```
<% @cardset.each do |cardset| %>
  <% cardset.each do |collection| %> # I get an error here
    <h1>Cards matching <%= collection.first[:name] %></h1>
    <% collection.each do |card| %>
      <%= image_tag "#{card[:image]}" %>
      <%= card[:name] %>
```

`cardset` should be an array of array of hashes that I iterate through (context)

Thanks!

Edit: Method in my controller responsible for this view:

```
def cards
    @collection = params[:imgur_link]
    unique_path = @collection.gsub("https://imgur.com/a/", "")
    @imgur = ImgurService.new(unique_path).call
    @ocr = OcrService.new(@imgur).call
    @cardset = CardsService.new(@ocr).call
end
```

CardService:

```
def initialize(ocrservice)
    @cards_from_ocr = ocrservice
  end

  def call
    match_ocr_with_ac
    # display_max_price
  end

  def match_ocr_with_ac
    confirmed_cards = []
    collected_cards = @cards_from_ocr

    collected_cards.each do |card|
      ac = Card.find_by('name like ?', "#{card}")

      if ac.nil?
        next
      else
        confirmed_cards << ac
      end
    end

    confirmed_cards
  end
```

Comment: That O(n) for the Card.find_by is highly inefficient. You probably have to change your data model a bit, depending on how the `collected_cards` are stored/retrieved. You're not setting `@cardset` in your controller, that's probably your bug.

Comment: Hey @ThomasR.Koll I am setting `@cardset` in my controller. (original post updated with CardService and controller method for this specific view). I think the problem is with AC object parsing part. Not sure where though.

Comment: `Card.find_by('name like ?', "#{card}")` returns only one element instead of an array, that's why you don't have an array of arrays. You only have one array with activerecord elements

Comment: @fanta Yes and no. You are completely correct if I have only 1 object in my DB with this specific "name". However, in my case I tend to have multiple objects with the same name (and with that call I get an array of those). My problem is, what happens when I only have 1 object with this specific name?

Also, if the object is not `nil` I still push it to an array that I iterate through later on. For some reason that array is empty (nil) even though I am 100% sure the data is correct. EDIT: If I have an array of AC elements, how can I turn it into array of hashes for example?

Comment: ruby has an Array method (in addition to the class) that will coerce single objects or nil into an array of a single object or empty array.  Objects that are already arrays won't be affected.

Comment: Why interpolation `card` (i.e. `find_by('name like ?', "#{card}")`) when you could just use it directly (i.e. `find_by('name like ?', card)`)? Also, that query will be the same as `find_by(name: card)` unless `card` has pattern matching characters in it or your database's `like` is case insensitive.

Comment: Your `CardService` method looks like a `@cards_from_ocr.map { |c| Card.find_by('name like ?', c.to_s).compact` invocation. If you don't care about missing entries, you could construct a 'name like X or name like Y ... or name like Z' query and get a flat array  in one database request. You have to convert to `where(...).to_a` if you want ocr result to be transformed to array of matching records.

Comment: Also, why `like` and no % substitution? if you are looking for case insensitive comparison, share your intent with case conversions, like `where('upper(name) = ?', card.to_s.upcase)`

Answer (score 2):

> The `find_by` method finds the first record matching some conditions ([source](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#find-by))

If you want to push into `confirmed_cards` an array of records with the same name you should do:

```
ac = Card.where('name like ?', "#{card}").to_a
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you there is a field in the `cards` table named `card_text` which has the string you want, the code you are looking for might be:

```
collected_cards.pluck(:card_text).each do |card_text|
  ac = Card.find_by('name like :pattern', pattern: "%#{card_text}%")
  next unless ac
  confirmed_cards << ac
end
```

or

```
confirmed_cards = collected_cards.pluck(:card_text).select do |card_text|
  Card.find_by('name like :pattern', pattern: "%#{card_text}%")
end
```

Pluck will take a collection of active record objects and return an array of just the field(s) you specified.

I like using bound parameters with the colon-name syntax better, because it decouples from the order of the bound parameters.